# Get object at index in Set<T>

Tags: swift, set

In Swift 1.2 there is a Set object, which you can use to create a static typed Set.

I cannot find out how to get the object at a certain index. It has a `subscript` that allows you to do the following: `mySet[setIndex]`.

This retrieves the object at that `setIndex`. But now I want to get an object from a certain `Int` index.

```
var myObject = mySet[sIndex];
```

But how do I create a SetIndex with a certain 'index'?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? `Set` is unordered, so indices wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

#### Swift 3 and newer

You can [`offsetBy:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2945022-index) from `.startIndex`:

```
let mySet: Set = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
mySet[mySet.index(mySet.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)] // -> something from the set.
```

#### Swift 2 (obsolete)

You can `advancedBy()` from `.startIndex`:

```
let mySet: Set = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
mySet[mySet.startIndex.advancedBy(2)] // -> something from the set.
```

#### Swift 1.x (obsolete)

Similar to `String`, you have to `advance()` from `.startIndex`:

```
let mySet: Set = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
mySet[advance(mySet.startIndex, 2)] // -> something from the set.
```

Comment: Note that the object at index 2 is not necessarily "c". Creating a set from an array (or array literal) does not preserve the order of the given elements.

Comment: Ah yes of course. It feels so unnatural to not use OO for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

A `Set` is unordered, so the *object at index* is an undefined behavior concept.

In practice, you may build an arbitrary ordered structure out of the Set, then pick an object at index in this ordered structure.

Maybe not optimal, but easy to achieve:

```
let myIndex = 1
let myObject = Array(mySet)[myIndex]
```

---

Note: if you need a random element, starting with Swift 4.2 you get the convenient solution:

```
let myRandomObject = mySet.randomElement()
```

Answer (score 1):

The Type of the index of the `Set` is not `Int`. So, you can't retrieve the object using `Int` subscript, i.e, `mySet[2]`.

You will have to use the index of type `Set<String>.Index`

```
let mySet: Set = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
var indices = [Set<String>.Index]()
for index in mySet.indices
{
    indices.append(index)
}
let thirdIndex = indices[2]
print(mySet[thirdIndex]) // prints d (for example)
```

However, unlike Array, Set is not ordered. Hence, as @Martin pointed out, the object at index 2 is not necessarily "c".