# Print one element of a Set in Swift

Tags: swift, set

I have a set like this:

```
var someItems: Set = [7,3,8]
```

And I want to print out only the  the number 7 of the set above.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get object at index in Set<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470843/get-object-at-index-in-sett)

Comment: A set is an unordered collection, so you cannot just 'get out the number 7' – you can check to see if the set contains 7, and if it does, then just print "7" yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the given problem, we can just print like this

> **Swift 3.0**

```
print(someItems.first!)
```

or

```
print(someItems[someItems.startIndex])
```

As **@Hamish** pointed out that set is an unordered collection and is not guaranteed to print out the first element which really makes sense, so in order to get 7, we can have a foreach loop

```
for (index,item) in someItems.enumerated() {
    if item == 7 {
        print("\(item) found at index = \(index)")
    }
}
```

Another way of checking

```
if someItems.contains(7) {
    print("7 is there")
}
```

Comment: A set is an unordered collection, so this is not guaranteed to print out the first element that was in the array literal.

Comment: @Hamish Makes sense. then only solution left to iterate the set and check when 7 comes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension to refer to the set member by index, so someItems[0] for example.

```
extension Set {

var length: Int {
    return count
}

subscript (i: Int) -> Set {
    return self[i ..< i + 1]
}

func substring(fromIndex: Int) -> Set {
    return self[Swift.min(fromIndex, length) ..< length]
}

func substring(toIndex: Int) -> Set {
    return self[0 ..< Swift.max(0, toIndex)]
}

subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> Set {
    let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: Swift.max(0, Swift.min(length, r.lowerBound)),
                                        upper: Swift.min(length, Swift.max(0, r.upperBound))))
    let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
    let end = index(start, offsetBy: range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
    return Set(self[start ..< end])
}
}
```