# looping thru IndexSet

Tags: swift, objective-c

The following quite simple for loop thru `NSIndexSet` must be ported to Swift

```objectivec
NSIndexSet indexSet = self.selectedRowIndexes;
for (NSUInteger index = indexSet.firstIndex; index != NSNotFound; index = [indexSet indexGreaterThanIndex:index]) {
    // do something with use of index
}
```

but i can not express same with a Swift `IndexSet` in a **for** loop as Swift does not allow C-style notations.

So how do does a ported version with same results from code above look like in Swift?

Comment: What about using `IndexSet`(there is a bridge) and use `enumerated()` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexset/1780173-enumerated ) on it? Or with `NSIndexSet`, you could use `enumerate(_:)`

Comment: Yes `IndexSet` is the question. Will not use bridge, as i kick out NSIndexSet then.. meaning `for (_, x) in indexSet.enumerated()` i hope, as `n` is just the index of the loop counting up but x the actual indexset value..

Comment: you could try something like this approach: `let indexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: 1..<5)
                for ndx in indexSet { print("---> ndx: \(ndx)") }`

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470843/get-object-at-index-in-sett)

Answer (score 2):

to wrap up what i learned..

```swift
var indexSet : IndexSet = IndexSet.init()

indexSet.insert(10)
indexSet.insert(12)
indexSet.insert(2)
indexSet.insert(64)

for n in indexSet {
    print("for n in indexSet -> \(n)")
}

for n in indexSet.enumerated() {
    print("for n in indexSet.enumerated() -> \(n)")
}

for n in indexSet.indices {
    print("for n in indexSet.indices -> \(n)")
}
```

results in

```swift
for n in indexSet -> 2
for n in indexSet -> 10
for n in indexSet -> 12
for n in indexSet -> 64
for n in indexSet.enumerated() -> (offset: 0, element: 2)
for n in indexSet.enumerated() -> (offset: 1, element: 10)
for n in indexSet.enumerated() -> (offset: 2, element: 12)
for n in indexSet.enumerated() -> (offset: 3, element: 64)
for n in indexSet.indices -> index 2 in a range of 2..<3 [range #1/4]
for n in indexSet.indices -> index 10 in a range of 10..<11 [range #2/4]
for n in indexSet.indices -> index 12 in a range of 12..<13 [range #3/4]
for n in indexSet.indices -> index 64 in a range of 64..<65 [range #4/4]
```

meaning, it is so simple, it is almost embarrassing

```
for n in indexSet {
    print("for n in indexSet -> \(n)")
}
```